# How change search btn on focus input?

Tags: html, css, button, onfocus

How change search btn on focus input? The initial state:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

What I want to get on focus of input. I need use only css, not js.

```html
<form action="">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

How make it?

Comment: Maybe you can try it with flexbox and flex direction.

Comment: @juzraai, How can I use  flex-direction if the focus is on the input?

Comment: You should avoid doing such thing for accessibility reasons.

Comment: You can play around with `order` like this: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy0fL8vm/1/)

Comment: I would find this swapping of input and button on focus horrifically confusing to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a flex container on the form and style the button with `order: -1` if it's focused. This will allow the button to appear before the input assuming other flex items are set to their initial order value of 0.

```
form {
    display: flex;
}

form input:focus + button {
    order: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started / one solution, I've used the `float` property, switching it from left to right on the `:focus` of the input. Hopefully this is roughly what you wanted, let me know if it wasn't.

---

## Demo

```css
button, input {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

input:focus {
  float: right;
}

form {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, have upvoted your more appropriate answer