# How change text of input placeholder on focus use only css?

Tags: html, css

How change text of input placeholder on focus use only css? The initial state:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

What I want to get on focus of input. I need use only css, not js.

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hello">
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: @zer00ne, different text in placeholder

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/XDutj/27/

Comment: @Waldir Bolanos, i need different text in placeholder, not color

Comment: Thats a job for javascript not css, unfortunately.

Comment: Is this [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612275/how-change-search-btn-on-focus-input#comment99799547_56612275)? Why are you asking almost the same question so many times?

Comment: @Martin that different questions.

Answer (score 1):

That really isn't what CSS is for.

CSS is for styling your content; HTML is for the actual content itself.

If you need to modify the content after the HTML has loaded, then that's what Javascript is for.

So the real answer to your question is: either modify the HTML directly or use Javascript.

Using Vanilla Javascript, you can change the input element using its id.

```js
function changeOutput(){
  document.getElementById('hi').value = "changed text";
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
INPUT: <input type="text" id="hi" placeholder="placeholding text" onfocus="changeOutput()"/>
```

[Live Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNPZRM)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky. We can use `:placeholder-shown`, and `:focus` on input elements, but unfortunately can't use `::after` or `::before` (as they are the only ways to adjust text content with pure css with `content` prop).

So the idea is to create an input container, an input and a fake placeholder inside as a span.

```css
.input-container {
  position: relative;
}

input:placeholder-shown + .placeholder::after {
  content: "placeholder";
}
input:placeholder-shown:focus + .placeholder::after {
  content: "focus";
}

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input placeholder=" "/>
  <span class="placeholder" />
</div>
```

This way we'll know when the placeholder is visible (no input made yet), and when is it on focus, and this way with the sibling selector, control the fake placeholders after,

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code. I attempted to fulfill your requirement using only CSS.

```css
/* Initial state */
  .input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }

  .input-placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 40px; /* Adjust line-height to vertically center */
    pointer-events: none; /* Ensure the placeholder text doesn't interfere with input */
    transition: top 0.3s, font-size 0.3s; /* Add smooth transition */
    color: #999; /* Placeholder text color */
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  
  input:focus::placeholder {
    opacity: 0; /* Show initial placeholder text when input is focused */
  }


  input:focus + .input-placeholder,
  input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .input-placeholder {
    top: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 3px;
  }
  
    input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .input-placeholder,
  input:focus:not(:placeholder-shown) + .input-placeholder {
    display: none; /* Hide placeholder when input is not empty and not focused */
  }
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="input-placeholder">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to change value of textbox so it will do through **Javascript** or **Jquery**.
There are two different things **CSS** and **Javascript**. if your problem is concern with styling CSS is a solution , if its functionality and logic Javascript is responsible

```
<input type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Search" onfocus="changeOutput()"/>

<script>
function changeOutput(){
  document.getElementById('txt').value = "Hello";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick in css file:

```
  input[type=text]:focus::placeholder {
    color: white;
  }
```